# (Angular 2/4/5/6) Changing navigation for browser back button

Tags: angular, routes, angular6

**Previous Question:**

I was trying to navigate the user to the main page (instead of the previous page) if the user clicked on the **browser back button**.

**Solution:**

I used a combination of candeactivateguard, hostlistener. Remember to declare your guard in the provider under your module file.

**deactivate.guard.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { CanDeactivate } from "@angular/router";

export interface CanComponentDeactivate {
  canDeactivate(): boolean;
}

@Injectable()
export class DeactivateGuard implements CanDeactivate<CanComponentDeactivate> {
  canDeactivate(component: CanComponentDeactivate): boolean {
    return component.canDeactivate();
  }
}
```

**lastpage.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject, HostListener } from "@angular/core";
export class LastPageComponent implements OnInit {
   disableSuccessNav = false;
   ngOnInit() {}
   constructor()
   //detects browser back button
   @HostListener("window:popstate")
   onPopState() {
     this.disableSuccessNav = true;
   }

   canDeactivate() {
      return !this.disableSuccessNav;
    }
```

Comment: Add `event.preventDefault()` in popstate method

Comment: thanks for your help, but event.preventDefault() doesn't work :( seems to go to the correct page for 3 seconds and then goes back to the previous page